python: scroll to a specific section of the page with selenium
Some web pages have multiple internal sections that can be scrolled separately, like messengers (for example, the right side scrolls inside the chat and the left side scrolls between contacts)
Or even like this box I'm typing in right now (it has its own scroll and the whole page has a separate scroll)
How can I specify in the selenium library to scroll down a certain amount in the desired section?
I attempted various methods suggested by others on Stack Overflow, but my issue remains unresolved.
